# How to create Java executable JAR from specific OSGi Plug-In(s)? Spefically an executable that has OSGi framework in it?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, executable-jar

Setup:

- Eclipse IDE
- Java (OSGi) Plug-In Development
- NO Maven or any other production add-on
- Run Configuration: OSGi Framework (type)

In General:
The OSGi plug-ins linking, running/testing in Eclipse is working just fine. Have multiple plugins that can be executed/launched as an application from within the Eclipse framework. Now trying to figure out how to export this stuff as an actual executable app (JAR) file(s).

Trying to create OSGi-based app that has a core app-module, along with (perhaps) a few embedded OSGi plugins, and allowing for external OSGi Plug-in JARs to be loaded dynamically. Basically the core app should have the OSGi framework embedded in it in order to allow for dynamically "loading" both the embedded plugins (found in same JAR) and any external plugins desired by the User. The external plugins will be self-contained as their own JARs. Plugins structure looks something like:

```
My-Core-Plugin-0
My-Embedded-Plugin-1
My-Embedded-Plugin-2
My-Embedded-Plugin-3
User-External-Plugin-4
User-External-Plugin-5
User-External-Plugin-6
User-External-Plugin-7
User-External-Plugin-8
etc.
```

So, i can export the external/user plug-ins via menu/options:

```
Export... | Plug-in Development | Deployable plug-ins and fragments
```

They end up as JAR files in a specified folder.

Now the "hard" part. How do i export the core-plugin and a few specified plugins as the "main" executable app-JAR? This may be incredibly simple but for whatever reason (possibly fatigue) it's evading me. I'd even settle for a single core plugin app from which i can dynamically install all the other external plug-ins (even the ones i want to "embed").

Looking for some menu/option like:

```
Export... | Plug-In Based Application | Export Executable OSGi-based JAR
(doesn't seem to exist)
```

So, how is this done?
Will the created core executable JAR contain an entire OSGi framework?
If so, will that framework be the Equinox Framework? (as that seems to be what is being used).

(Note i feel like i'm missing something that's right in front of my face.)

Thanks very much from a very tired programmer.

Comment: Perhaps the [Apache Felix Framework Launching and Embedding](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html) documentation could provide pointers on how to embed and run OSGi-framework in your project. You could also try digging [Apache Karaf](https://github.com/apache/karaf) and [PaxExam](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2) source code on how this is handled in those projects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have already looked at the Apache Felix docs and have tried to use Karaf. It seems my problem has more to do with modular Java vs. non-modular Java, and accessing classes in a non-modular jar from a modular java project (one that will have a module-info bundled with it). I'll be asking about that in another question i post. Thanks much.

Comment: If by non-modular you mean jars that are missing OSGi headers you can add them by using maven-bundle-plugin when packaging bundles are just jars with OSGi headers after all. In case of problematic 3rd party dependencies you can create a bundle that embeds these dependencies and exports the packages you need.